# Is using Java 8 Time Classes inside a Wrapper Class Thread Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, java-8

I'm converting our application's use of JodaTime/Java.utils time to Java 8's... we use Date a lot (which isn't thread safe), so rather than change all those references, I tried to use Java 8's classes and leverage it. Here's what I came up with:

When testing this, it worked fine. We are using Spring, and have two ScheduledExecutorTasks (basically threads) running delta jobs, and using the "format" portion of this code to format dates in ISO_ZULU format.

However, this doesn't work. The formatted time appears incorrect, and it could be causing a 404 error. It's hard to test because it's our QA servers running it, it doesn't happen locally.

My question is, is what I'm doing safe? If not, is it because of my use of Date? Would using a thread safe class (such as Instant) solve my problems?

```
public class DateTimeUtils {

    public enum Pattern{
        ISO_ZULU("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),
        AMERICAN("MM-dd-yyyy"),
        UTC("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"),
        TIME_TRAVEL("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        MERIDIEM("a"),
        HOUR_MINUTES("h:mm"),
        MILITARY("HH:mm");

        private final String pattern;
        Pattern(String pattern){
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return pattern;
        }
    }

    protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(DateTimeUtils.class);
    private static final String UTC_ZONE_ID = "Etc/UTC";
    private static final String DEFAULT_ZONE_ID = ZoneId.systemDefault().getId();

    public static String format(Pattern pattern, Date date){
        return format(pattern.toString(), date, false);
    }

    public static String format(Pattern pattern, Date date, boolean arcTimeZone){
        return format(pattern.toString(), date, arcTimeZone);
    }

    public static String format(String pattern, Date date, boolean arcTimeZone){
        ZoneId zoneId;
        if(arcTimeZone){
            zoneId = getTimeZone();
        }else{
            zoneId = ZoneId.of(UTC_ZONE_ID);
        }
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(zoneId).format(date.toInstant());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the use of `Date` would figure into it -- you don't store a reference to the `Date` object and thus other threads could never have access to it. Can you provide a specific method invocation that causes the behaviour? You don't provide any details as to which `format()` you are calling or whether `arcTimeZone` is true, etc etc.

Comment: Hey, sorry. 

Format is called by a ScheduledExecutorBean, running a ScheduledExecutorTask, calling a method, "load". Load then creates a new Date "now" and passes that along to another method, where it is then formatted. Format is called multiple times using the same instance of Date.

Oh, and arcTimeZone is false in all these cases :)

Comment: And if some other bit of code uses this exact same `format()` method, all is well, and it's right on time?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Yes. What you are doing seems to be thread-safe.

## Details

You are passing in a reference to a `java.util.Date` object on each call. That reference is not held, it goes away at the end of that static method call. So no other thread sees that that particular reference, as commented by dcsohl.

Thread-safety is about contention over shared resources. In the code shown here, you are not sharing that `Date` reference. You may be sharing it in *other* code on other threads which might be a problem. But no problem given what you have shown us here.

The java.time classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and are entirely thread-safe afaik. So no worries on that side of things.

I do not know about the thread-safety of `LogFactory.getLog`, but that is outside the scope of your Question.

**You may have a thread-safety issue *elsewhere*** if that passed `Date` is used in other code in other threads. Read below for suggestion to not pass that `Date`.

## Suggestions

Some other issues, beyond your question about thread-safety.

### Adapt the old code, not new

I suggest you change your argument from `Date` to `Instant`. In all the calling code, change the call to pass `myExampleDate.toInstant()` rather than passing `myExampleDate`. This makes your code more self-documenting in that you are migrating *towards* java.time and *away* from the legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.). If that is the goal, you don’t want to bend the new code to the old ways, the old code should bend towards the new code (where doing so is low-risk/low-cost).

Take as inspiration how java.time adds new conversion methods to the *old* legacy classes, as with the `Date.toInstant()` seen here. The **new classes know nothing of the old legacy classes**. The legacy classes have the responsibility to "get with the program".

### Default time zone

> private static final String DEFAULT_ZONE_ID = ZoneId.systemDefault().getId();

That line is not as final and permanent as you might be intending. The JVM’s current default time zone may change at any moment *during* runtime as your code executes. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can at any moment change the current default time zone with a call to [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-).

Also, the default for the JVM on startup in must implementations of Java is to use the current value of the host OS’ default time zone. This is an externality beyond your control, so any sysadmin may unintentionally be changing the behavior of your app. Ditto for a time zone setting passed as an argument to the JVM’s launch script.

I suggest you drop that line. Instead, always pass the desired/expected time zone in all your code. Never rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

When you truly want the current default, make a call to `ZoneId.systemDefault()` each time, to get the fresh truth rather than a cached value that may be stale (no longer true). This also makes your code more self-documenting.

### UTC constant

> private static final String UTC_ZONE_ID = "Etc/UTC";

The java.time classes already offer a constant for UTC: [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). So no need for that constant of yours.